# Private app on Appstore

Tags: android, ios, app-store

Would an app that requires users to purchase a non-digital product/service to get a login to the app be allowed on the Appstore (iPhone and Android)? If not what would be the correct method for distribution of private app?

Comment: I think a little more detail is required in order to understand exactly what you're talking about. I have a banking app, which obviously requires a bank account to log in before it is useful. What is the difference in this case?

Comment: Yes that is very similar to what I had in mind. As an example to explain my point: An Airline app that is unusable unless you purchase a ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of apps in the app store that require something external. Nest app, for example, is probably pretty useless without a Nest thermostat. I think the app should just need to behave nicely if you don't have the external thing, the ticket in your case.

Comment: That's a good example! I think I'll download it to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

At least for Android (Google Play) there should be no problem if you don't force your users in app to purchase something outside of Google Wallet (e.g. in app purchases with PayPal etc., but I guess for buying tickets it's okay - if it is not done inside the app).

Here are their terms for more details: [Google Play Terms](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

An other way would be more open markets like Bazaar (Android) or host it on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

For private apps you can distribute your app under an Enterprise developer account. see [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). but you have to pay more ($299/year)